# parsing emails to identify keywords

Tags: python, text

I'm looking to parse through a list of email text to identify keywords. lets say I have this following list:

```
sentences = [['this is a paragraph there should be lots more words here'],
 ['more information in this one'],
 ['just more words to be honest, not sure what to write']]
```

I want to check to see if words from a keywords list are in any of these sentences in the list, using regex. I wouldn't want `informations` to be captured, only `information`

```
keywords = ['information', 'boxes', 'porcupine']
```

was trying to do something like:

```
['words' in words for [word for word in [sentence for sentence in sentences]]
```

or

```
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence.split(' ')
```

ultimately would like to filter down current list to elements that only have the keywords I've specified.

```
keywords = ['information', 'boxes']

sentences = [['this is a paragraph there should be lots more words here'],
     ['more information in this one'],
     ['just more words to be honest, not sure what to write']]

output: [False, True, False]
```

or ultimately:

```
parsed_list = [['more information in this one']]
```

Comment: Your wordings seems confusing. Kindly edit your question to include the desired output.

Comment: What about overlapping matches? Say you have `"cat"` in your `keywords` list, should it match `"caterpillar"` or `"concatenate"` or `"ducat"`? What about punctiation marks as word separators?

Comment: Good Q @zwer, I wouldn't want that to count. It would be some form of regex separating that word using spaces or punctuation. I would want to pass it a word and only have that word be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner to solve your problem. I find using lambda syntax is easier to read than nested list comprehensions.

```
keywords = ['information', 'boxes']

sentences = [['this is a paragraph there should be lots more words here'],
             ['more information in this one'],
             ['just more words to be honest, not sure what to write']]


results_lambda = list(
    filter(lambda sentence: any((word in sentence[0] for word in keywords)), sentences))

print(results_lambda)
```

`[['more information in this one']]`

Comment: just one small tip: you could use a generator, instead of having a list when using with any: any(word in sentence[0] for word in keywords) would suffice. using generators is space efficient in such scenarios, and matters when size of lists can be huge.

Comment: Good idea. The generator would evaluate the sequence and stop on the first value rather then expanding the entire expression first. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find sentences which have all the words in your keywords list?

If so, then you could use a set of those keywords and filter each sentence based on whether all words are present in the list:

One way is:

```
keyword_set = set(keywords)
n = len(keyword_set) # number of keywords
def allKeywdsPresent(sentence):
    return len(set(sentence.split(" ")) & keyword_set) == n # the intersection of both sets should equal the keyword set

filtered = [sentence for sentence in sentences if allKeywdsPresent(sentence)]

# filtered is the final set of sentences which satisfy your condition

# if you want a list of booleans:
boolean_array = [allKeywdsPresent(sentence[0]) for sentence in sentences]
```

There could be more optimal ways to do this (e.g. the set created for each sentence in allKeywdsPresent could be replaced with a single pass over all elements, etc.) But, this is a start.

Also, understand that using a set means duplicates in your keyword list will be eliminated. So, if you have a list of keywords with some duplicates, then use a dict instead of the set to keep a count of each keyword and reuse above logic.

From your example, it seems enough to have at least one keyword match. Then you need to modify allKeywdsPresent() [Maybe rename if to anyKeywdsPresent]:

```
def allKeywdsPresent(sentence):
   return any(word in keyword_set for word in sentence.split())
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the question indicating all of the keywords need to be present. The example presented indicates two keywords with the desired result containing only one of those keywords.

Comment: @tgikal: agreed, i modified the function used for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a quick list comprehension!

`lists = [['here is one sentence'], ['and here is another'], ['let us filter!'], ['more than one word filter']]
filter = ['filter', 'one']
result = list(set([x for s in filter for x in lists if s in x[0]]))
print(result)`

result:
`[['let us filter!'], ['more than one word filter'], ['here is one sentence']]`
hope  this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only whole words and not just substrings you'll have to account for all word separators (whitespace, puctuation, etc.) and first split your sentences into words, then match them against your keywords. The easiest, although not fool-proof way is to just use the regex `\W` (non-word character) classifier and split your sentence on such occurences..

Once you have the list of words in your text and list of keywords to match, the easiest, and probably most performant way to see if there is a match is to just do set intersection between the two. So:

```
# not sure why you have the sentences in single-element lists, but if you insist...
sentences = [['this is a paragraph there should be lots more words here'],
             ['more information in this one'],
             ['just more disinformation, to make sure we have no partial matches']]

keywords = {'information', 'boxes', 'porcupine'}  # note we're using a set here!

WORD = re.compile(r"\W+")  # a simple regex to split sentences into words

# finally, iterate over each sentence, split it into words and check for intersection
result = [s for s in sentences if set(WORD.split(s[0].lower())) & keywords]
# [['more information in this one']]
```

So, how does it work - simple, we iterate over each of the sentences (and lowercase them for a good measure of case-insensitivity), then we split the sentence into words with the aforementioned regex. This means that, for example, the first sentence will split into:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'paragraph', 'there', 'should', 'be', 'lots', 'more', 'words', 'here']
```

We then convert it into a set for blazing fast comparisons (`set` is a hash sequence and intersections based on hashes are extremely fast) and, as a bonus, this also gets rid duplicate words.

Fnally, we do the set intersection against our `keywords` - if anything is returned these two sets have at least one word in common, which means that the `if ...` comparison evaluates to `True` and, in that case, the current sentence gets added to the result.

Final note - beware that while `\W+` might be enough to split sentences into words (certainly better than a whitespace split only), it's far from perfect and not really suitable for all languages. If you're serious about word processing take a look at some of the NLP modules available for Python, such as the [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/).